# Beta Adjusted Return

Tags: sharpe-ratio, beta, return

I'm a bit confused about the definition of the 'Beta Adjusted Return', say I have benchmark whose return is $r$ and a stock whose return is $R$, the beta adjusted return is defined as

$$                           \frac{R-\beta r}{\sigma}                                                          $$

where $\beta$ is the beta coefficient, and $\sigma$ the stock's volatility.

Isn't it related to the Sharpe Ratio, defined by $\frac{R-r}{\sigma} $ ? What definition should we use?

Thanks

Comment: Suppose you have some market model such that $R=\alpha+\beta r+\varepsilon$. Here, $r$ is some source of risk. I ignore the risk-free rate. Then, $\mathbb{E}[R]-\beta\mathbb{E}[r]=\alpha$ is the outperformance of your stock and $\sigma$ is the total risk of your stock. In the CAPM world, $\alpha=0$ for all assets. The classical Sharpe ratio compares excess returns to total risk, your fraction, $\frac{\bar{R}-\hat{\beta}\bar{r}}{\hat{\sigma}}$, compares returns (after correcting for systematic risk) to total risk.

Comment: I don't think you need to divide by vol for beta adj returns.

Comment: Agree with @LazyCat. The more commonly used Beta adjusted return is the Treynor Ratio: $\frac{R-r}{\beta}$?